build.gradle unable to find tasks for DesktopLauncher.main
So I've been learning Java and thought I'd try and follow along a YouTube tutorial to make flappy bird using libGDX and Android Studio. I'm on part 9 currently and I think I have everything correct so far but now when I attempt to run the application it opens to the menu state and when I click to change to the play state it stops responding. I'll provide the error message I got with stacktrace below

Cannot locate tasks that match ':desktop:DesktopLauncher.main()' as task 'DesktopLauncher.main()' not found in project ':desktop'.

and the exception here

Exception is:
org.gradle.execution.TaskSelectionException: Cannot locate tasks that match ':desktop:DesktopLauncher.main()' as task 'DesktopLauncher.main()' not found in project ':desktop'.
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskSelector.lambda$throwTaskSelectionException$1(DefaultTaskSelector.java:105)
at org.gradle.api.problems.internal.DefaultProblemReporter.throwing(DefaultProblemReporter.java:48)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskSelector.throwTaskSelectionException(DefaultTaskSelector.java:101)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskSelector.getSelection(DefaultTaskSelector.java:86)
at org.gradle.execution.selection.DefaultBuildTaskSelector.resolveTaskName(DefaultBuildTaskSelector.java:98)
at org.gradle.execution.commandline.CommandLineTaskParser.parseTasks(CommandLineTaskParser.java:49)
at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildTaskScheduler.scheduleRequestedTasks(TaskNameResolvingBuildTaskScheduler.java:51)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildTaskScheduler.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultTasksBuildTaskScheduler.java:72)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$0(DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.java:46)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withReplacedLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:360)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$DefaultBuildProjectRegistry.withMutableStateOfAllProjects(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:240)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$DefaultBuildProjectRegistry.withMutableStateOfAllProjects(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:233)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.java:45)
at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$0(VintageBuildModelController.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$1(StateTransitionController.java:99)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$2(StateTransitionController.java:114)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:110)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:98)
at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.scheduleRequestedTasks(VintageBuildModelController.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController$DefaultWorkGraphBuilder.addRequestedTasks(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:404)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$0(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:41)
at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$populateWorkGraph$7(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:189)
at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildWorkPreparer.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildWorkPreparer.java:42)
at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer$PopulateWorkGraph.populateTaskGraph(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:106)
at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer$PopulateWorkGraph.run(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:92)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.populateWorkGraph(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:67)
at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$populateWorkGraph$8(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:189)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$1(StateTransitionController.java:99)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$2(StateTransitionController.java:114)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:110)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:98)
at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:189)
at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildWorkGraphController$DefaultBuildWorkGraph.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildWorkGraphController.java:169)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildController.java:76)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph$DefaultBuildTreeWorkGraphBuilder.withWorkGraph(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$1(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:41)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph$DefaultBuildTreeWorkGraph$1.run(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:209)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph$DefaultBuildTreeWorkGraph.scheduleWork(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:204)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:37)
at org.gradle.configurationcache.VintageBuildTreeWorkController$scheduleAndRunRequestedTasks$1.apply(VintageBuildTreeWorkController.kt:36)
at org.gradle.configurationcache.VintageBuildTreeWorkController$scheduleAndRunRequestedTasks$1.apply(VintageBuildTreeWorkController.kt:35)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.withNewWorkGraph(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:112)
at org.gradle.configurationcache.VintageBuildTreeWorkController.scheduleAndRunRequestedTasks(VintageBuildTreeWorkController.kt:35)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$scheduleAndRunTasks$1(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:119)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:169)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$7(StateTransitionController.java:169)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:169)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:116)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.scheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.scheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:71)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:140)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:123)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.execute(InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitProblems.execute(InitProblems.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:71)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:60)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:71)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:264)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:128)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:92)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:39)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:64)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)

Not sure if all that is needed or not. But here is the build.gradle from the desktop folder.
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = ["../assets"]

project.ext.mainClassName = "com.jakemcdaniel.DesktopLauncher"
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../assets")

import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem

tasks.register('run', JavaExec) {
    dependsOn classes
    mainClass = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true

    if (OperatingSystem.current() == OperatingSystem.MAC_OS) {
        // Required to run on macOS
        jvmArgs += "-XstartOnFirstThread"
    }
}

tasks.register('debug', JavaExec) {
    dependsOn classes
    mainClass = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
    debug = true
}

tasks.register('dist', Jar) {
    duplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE)
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
    dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    with jar
}


dist.dependsOn classes

eclipse.project.name = appName + "-desktop"

java.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

and here is the DesktopLauncher.java incase this is necessary
package com.jakemcdaniel;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Application;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration;
import com.jakemcdaniel.FlappyGame;

// Please note that on macOS your application needs to be started with the -XstartOnFirstThread JVM argument
public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration config = new Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration();
        config.setWindowedMode(FlappyGame.WIDTH, FlappyGame.HEIGHT);
        config.setTitle(FlappyGame.TITLE);
        config.setForegroundFPS(60);
        new Lwjgl3Application(new FlappyGame(), config);
    }
}


Let me know if I need to provide anything else. And thanks for any help I've been stuck trying to figure this out for a while now.
I've tried to use the source from the YouTube video on the guys github to see what his build.gradle looked like but the video is from 8 years ago so there's a lot of deprecated features in it and I'm not sure what to take from it if anything. Other than that I thought at first it might be a memory issue so I went over all the classes to make sure anything unused was disposed when it needed to be.

I think issue might be in your build.gradle file that is in desktop folder.
In your build file, you wrote  project.ext.mainClassName = "com.jakemcdaniel.DesktopLauncher".
In github repo that you provided, the file is placed in desktop folder, so the repo owner wrote this  line by adding "desktop" keyword(where he placed his file) before java file name as shown in below,  project.ext.mainClassName = "com.brentaureli.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher".
So, my advice is to check your folder structure and see where did you placed DeskttopLauncher file exactly, if it is under desktop named folder and not in the main directory of project then you also have to add "desktop"(folder name I supposed) keyword in your build gradle file where you wrote the package name.
I hope this works for you!!!

Thank you for the response! I tried what you suggested. This is what I renamed the line in the build.gradle to (project.ext.mainClassName = "desktop.src.com.jakemcdaniel.DesktopLauncher") not sure if this is correct the folder structure is desktop > src > com.jakemcdaniel > DesktopLauncher. Either way though this doesn't seem to be the solution. The program still runs but it also stops responding and gives the same error when I close it out with task manager.

Okay!!! I thought it is a folder structure issue based on the line written in build.gradle file.  But as you provided folder names, it seems you given one folder name as com.jakemacdaniel. It is a package name and might it is occuring the issue. So my advise it either rename the folder name or remove that folder and place the DesktopLauncher file directly in src folder, then try this one    (project.ext.mainClassName = "desktop.src.DesktopLauncher") or you can try this as well   project.ext.mainClassName = "com.jakemcdaniel.src.desktop.DesktopLauncher")

I figured out the problem. It seemed odd to me that the build.gradle would be the issue when that file is generated by libGDX so I rewatched the YouTube video to see if I had either missed something or I added a typo. And of course, like so many issues in coding I had accidentally put a 1 instead of i inside of a for loop so it was constantly generating new objects rather than checking to see if it should keep adding them.  Thank you so much for your help!

Oh!! What a silly error haha!! It's great to heard you that you solved it!!! Happy coding.
